# UITableView reload issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have UITableView inside UIScrollView and implemented paging with which I get 10 records in each page. I am facing a problem when after the IndexPath row is 9 then again UITableView reloads cells starting from row 2 due to which all the Pages are loaded once. Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if listData != nil{
        print("list count in numberOfRowsInSection\(listData?.count)")
        return (listData?.count)!
    }
    return 0

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("CellForRowIndexPath:\(indexPath.row)")
    let cell: NewPostCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewPostCell") as? NewPostCell ??
        NewPostCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "NewPostCell")
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.updateWithModel(self.listData![indexPath.row] as AnyObject)
    cell.tbleUpdateDelegate = self
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.accessoryType = .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("in will display row - \(indexPath.row)")

    if pageNumber >= totalPages {
        return
    }
    else
    {
        if (listData?.count)! == 10*pageNumber{
            if (listData?.count)! - 3 == indexPath.row{
                if !boolHitApi{
                    boolHitApi = true
                    return
                }
                pageNumber += 1
                self.callService()
            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    callService()
}
func callService(){
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    setPageToOne()
    ProfileApiStore.shared.requestToGetProfile(loggedInUserId: UserStore.shared.userId, userId:  UserStore.shared.userIdToViewProfile, limit: "10", page: String(self.pageNumber), completion: {(result) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.totalPages = result.totalPages!
        if self.listData?.count == 0  || (self.pageNumber as AnyObject) as! Int == (1 as AnyObject) as! Int{
            self.listData = result.userdata?.newPostData
        } else {
            self.listData = self.listData! +  (result.userdata?.newPostData)!
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: `self.tableView.reloadData()` reloads the table view data.. so will reload all visible rows

Comment: So should I not reload UITableView? What is alternative to this? please suggest

Comment: You can manage the updated data manually by using `insertRows(at: indexPath, with: animation)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows

Comment: I have changed my callService() method to this:

Comment: self.listData = result.userdata?.newPostData
                let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.listData!.count-1), section:0)
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)

Comment: My application gets crashed with the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)

Comment: @Scriptable please let me know how can I use insertRows(at: indexPath, with: animation) to update data manually.

Comment: You need to do beginUpdates() insertRows(at: [indexPath], with:) endUpdates(). Apart from that.. isn't `self.listData = result.userdata?.newPostData` overwriting the original rows with the new rows?

Comment: Ok got it, but I could not understand what you want me to change in: self.listData = result.userdata?.newPostData  as I get data from web service and assigning it to array which is let.listData.

Comment: u want to add the new rows to the array... something like `self.listData.append(contentsOf: result.userdata?.newPostData)`

Comment: I changed code to this:                                                                    
       self.listData = result.userdata?.newPostData
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.listData!.count-1), section:0)
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: But App crashes with this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: I'll try and post a code example, you are adding 10 items to the array and only inserting one row, thats the issue

Comment: I believe i am adding rows as my code is insertRows. Thanks

Comment: you create a **single** indexPath, so you tell the tableView to insert a **single** row. try my code below

Answer (score 0):

The code you mentioned in the comments adds 10 rows to the datasource (self.listData) but you are only calling insertRows with one row.

You could loop through them, adding an item to the array and adding a row each time:

```
func callService() {
    ProfileApiStore.shared.requestToGetProfile(loggedInUserId: UserStore.shared.userId, userId:  UserStore.shared.userIdToViewProfile, limit: "10", page: String(self.pageNumber), completion: {(result) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.totalPages = result.totalPages!
        let newItems = result.userdata?.newPostData

        tableView.beingUpdates()
        for item in newItems {
            self.listData.append(item)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.listData!.count-1), section:0) // shouldn't this be just self.listData!.count as your adding a new row?
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scriptable I an going to try this code

Comment: I am getting this error with the above code after correcting self.listData!.count-1 to self.listData!.count : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 10 into section 0, but there are only 10 rows in section 0 after the update